# VBA - Excel Formula Caclulation

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a code in vba were produce a simple calculation, activesheet.cells(i,3) = activesheet.cells(i,2) * activesheet.cells(i,1)

My question here is when i run once the code and then change the values on cells(i,2) and cells(i,1), i want the the cells(i,3)cell to automatically calculate the new value

For example if cells(i,2) = 3 and cells(i,1) = 2 then cells(i,3) = 6
I want to change the manually the values in excel to cells(i,2) = 4, cells(i,1) = 4, without running again the code I want automatically the cells(i,3) = 16

This code be in a for loop

Comment: So why use VBA ? You will have to handle a worksheet or workbook event to get this behaviour and doing so can have unwanted side effects. Why not just use a formula if your logic is so simple?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie is right. The only way I know to achieve what you've described is to subscribe to the **Worksheet.Change** and **Worksheet.Calculate** events and handle the calculation in those; but please don't do that.

Comment: there is more coding behind this and on the output I don't want to enter any formulas. i want by changing the values on the cells, the sum of those to change automatically.  i know there is something like activesheet.FormulaR1C1 that works but I want to use this in a loop

Comment: Have you attempted to code it in VBA so far? If so, can you please share your code?

Comment: The guy told VBA, whats your problem man?

Comment: @Pashiamas Calm down. Very often people ask for VBA just because they're not aware that their issue can be solved without. It's perfectly alright to challenge the VBA request.

Comment: @Pashiamas - if you asked a baker to show you how to bake a cake but you said you wanted to use marmite and coffee grounds instead of eggs and flour, do you think he should a) advise you not to do that or b) forever be associated with the resulting inedible mess?

Comment: Yummm - coffee & Vegemite flavoured cake! :) :)

Answer (score 3):

Try making a string that contains the addresses, like this

```
activesheet.cells(i,3) = "=" & activesheet.cells(i,2).Address(0, 0) & "*" &  activesheet.cells(i,1).Address(0, 0)
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that's what @Cadman wants but it correctly answers the question :-D

Comment: @JonDavies - In a comment the OP says that they have heard that they can use `activesheet.FormulaR1C1`, so my guess is this is very close to what the OP is after.  (Although, I guess we could argue that it should be `Activesheet.Cells(i, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*RC[-1]"`)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Macro Event.

Right click on the sheet you want to work with and select view code.
Copy an paste this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 On Error GoTo errorHandler
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 Dim lastrow As Long, rango As Range, Hoja As Worksheet
  Set Hoja = ActiveSheet
  lastrow = Application.CountA(Hoja.Range("A:A"))
  Set rango = Hoja.Range("A1:C" & lastrow)
  rango(lastrow, 3).Value = rango(lastrow, 1).Value * rango(lastrow, 2).Value
errorHandler:
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]